# Error when use method String.replaceAll

Tags: java

I use this code to get a string from `JTextArea`, then replace string by string from the string I got it from `JTextArea`.

```
String data = MainTextArea.getText().toString();
data = data.replaceAll("(", "<");
MainTextArea.setText(data);
```

I got an error in the second line of this code which says:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1

What should I do to solve this?

I don't know if there is more information should be provided to the question to be clear.

**Update :**

I am using a `HashMap<string,string>` to replace many strings this strings may contains some chars like `"("` which needs the \ before it how to know that this string need those \ when i use this part of code

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : settingfile.CharactersMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " | " + entry.getValue());
    data = data.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `replaceAll` which takes a regular expression as input rather than just `replace` which is rather simpler?

Comment: i want to replace all the string and i think that replace only replace one string not all it's repeats is that right?

Comment: @noname that's a not-unreasonable thought, given the name, but no, all matches are replaced.

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine using replace i was thought that replace, replace only one occurrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `(` using `\\`. Try this:

```
data = data.replaceAll("\\(", "<");
```

[Docs for replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

As pointed by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), it would be simple to use [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
data = data.replace('(', '<');
```

Comment: It would be simpler just to use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: thank you it worked fine but i have a question please how to know if this string need this \\ before it as i take this from a HashMap<string,string> to replace many strings i will update the question now

Comment: @Aniket actually, it would be simpler to use `data.replace('(', '<')`. Using `char` instead of `String` makes it much faster, because it doesn't have to use the heavyweight regex machinery internally.

Comment: @AndyTurner You won :)

Comment: @noname http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html might help

Answer (score 0):

Diferent method from this family `public String replace(char oldChar,
             char newChar)` doesnt take regex machinery.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

So Your code can be

```
data = data.replace('(', '<');
```

Hope, non-regex version has better performance too